# htaccess *.php to *.html object not found error

Tags: mod-rewrite, http-status-code-404

I am trying to transform URLs from `index.php` to `index.html`, `servicii.php` to `servicii.html` and so on.

I wrote in my `.htaccess` file, which is in my [site](http://alexbtest.hostei.com/)  root the following code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>  
    RewriteEngine On  
    RewriteBase     /
    RewriteRule     ^(.*)\.php$   $1.html [R=permanent] 
</IfModule> 
?>
```

But when I follow "Prima pagina" (Home) or "Servicii" (the only 2 pages created on site) it gives me a 404 error

Also, I have the code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase  /fetesti/
    RewriteRule  ^(.*)\.php$   $1.html [R=permanent] 
</IfModule>
```

on my local machine, which is XAMPP based. It gives me Object not found 404, and on my Apache log:

> file not found [...]/index.html;

I know the rewrite engine is working (I wrote gibberish and it gave me 505 internal server error and made other tests)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: would you be so kind as to format your code into code blocks so that we can easily read it? it helps a lot. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try just remove [R] permanent redirect, and switch extensions in rule

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>  
    RewriteEngine On  
    RewriteBase     /
    RewriteRule     ^(.*)\.html$   $1.php
</IfModule>
```