# Retrieving GET[] information, from URL forwarding using htaccess

Tags: php, apache, url-rewriting, get

I have an  `index.php` and `news.php` and `.htaccess` files in my `localhost/DIRECTORY/AID/`
folder, and I am basically trying send/receive data from `index.php` to `news.php`

This is a function inside the `index.php`, which creates a link from database query, and echos out a title of an article.

```
function news_preview() {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM updates ORDER BY update_id DESC LIMIT 5  ";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $url = "/news/$row[update_id]/" . preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9-_]/', '_',
            $row['update_title']);
        echo "<a href=\"$url\">  " . substr($row['update_title'], 0, 26) . "...</a><br/>";
    }
}

echo news_preview();
```

Now, here is what the `.htaccess` looks like

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^news/([0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)$ DIRECTORY/AID/news.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Now, to the problem. Basically, when I clicked on the link (generated by `news_preview()` ) 
shown in the `index.php`, All I get in the **news.php** page is nothing. But, probably because I am trying to use the  `$_GET['title']` Although, I am not certain if that is how we retrieve data. But, the links take me to `http://localhost/news/46/This_is_news_title`
which is perfect, but I am getting the `Object Not Found` error

Below, is the image of the error I am getting.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure your htaccess file is being applied? If you had a bunch of gibberish in it, do you get a 500 server error? Where is the htaccess file located?

Comment: In the AID/ folder along with `index.php` & `news.php` The problem, is I don't know how to get the data from the url in the `news.php `

Comment: If you enter this URL in browser: `http://localhost/news.php?id=46` does it work?

Comment: Are you purposely not doing anything with the second capture group in the htaccess redirect? Are you expecting to be able to read it with `$_GET['title']`?

Comment: @anubhava No it gives me the same error

Comment: @freejosh That is the problem. I used to read it with `$_GET['id']` when I didn't need to format the url, but now that I do, I don't know how to get the data

Comment: Ok can you try: `http://localhost/DIRECTORY/AID/news.php?id=46` ?

Comment: @anubhava tried it, it gave me a blank page. No errors.. nothing. just blank

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: The code of `news.php` is missing. Also verify that the links you output (view source, check with browser copy link location) are correct firsthand.

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12086866/apache-mod-rewrite-displays-object-not-found-404

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11442119/object-not-found-xampp

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10537910/htaccess-php-to-html-object-not-found-error

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9281381/notfound-html-is-not-found

Comment: @hakre I have all codes in news.php, but the style is included using the include function, the problem is .htaccess will not include it

Comment: .htaccess does *never* include files. Better make yourself more comfortable with rewrite basics: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/intro.html - Also you left a comment some days ago everything is solved (because you placed the file in a wrong directory). Double check you *know* where to place each file and while.

Comment: No actually, I did not misplaced anything, when I was trying the URL forwarding it was from simple pages with nothing included in them, but when I included other files, it wont work. So, I can still make the URL work, but the problem as I said is including files only. @hakre

Comment: Another misconception. This is no URL forwarding. You should better take care what you communicate which is often a sign how you "understand" things, better get this all streamlined with the standard documents. Also reduce your question to the minimum simplified possible case that is demonstrating the issue. There should be no PHP code needed for this *at all*. Please edit your question and reduce it to the bare needed minimum.

Comment: Why so many downvotes? seriously. This is a good question... +1

Comment: thanks @pattyd unfortunately, everyone that hates me in SE, likes to come here and drop me a down vote, I have gotten used to it.

Comment: @phpNoOb most StackOverflowers think that they are better than other programmers, so they downvote everything. :( thankfully we aren't like them ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put this code in the `htdocs/.htaccess`:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^news/([0-9]+)/.*$ /DIRECTORY/AID/news.php?id=$1 [QSA,L,NC]
```

Comment: Still object not found error. is the news.php supposed to be empty?

Comment: I edited my answer, above will goto `htdocs/.htaccess` (remove earlier  .htaccess). However you have to make `http://localhost/DIRECTORY/AID/news.php?id=46` work or tell me how are you loading your `news.php` URL?

Comment: Well, this is promising. I did as what you asked, and I did not get any errors when I click on the link, but only a blank page. The url has changed into `http://localhost/news/46/Third_news_test` which is good, and no errors. But, still nothing. I am confused, I have the script in index.php, but I need the news to be displayed in news.php , so what acctually needs to be inside the news.php?

Comment: Your `news.php` should retrieve id like this: `$id=$_GET['id'];` and use this `$id` to query the database for news article content and then display the new content.

Comment: It took me two weeks and two posts (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13557696/url-re-writing-not-working-properly) to solve this problem. Finally, it's Done. Thank God. I got it now. It was all due to placing the .htaccess file in the wrong folder. Thanks a Million anubhava

Comment: place a bounty, because I am having trouble including the css file, which is inside a header.php at the news.php page

Comment: Actually `include('header.php')` directive has nothing to do with .htaccess since server side includes are managed by PHP without any knowledge of Apache and it all happens in single Apache request. Reason why your css, js, images are not working because you are not using absolute URLs for them. e.g. instead of `style.css` use `/style.css`

Comment: Thanks but that did not solve it, the template works fine, when all files are included and IF i delete what is inside the .htaccess code, but when I include the .htaccess code, then all includes do not get included

Comment: You will need to provide more details like your latest .htaccess code, an independent PHP code snippet with mentioned includes and clear marking like which part of your code is not working.

Comment: everything worked. It turns out, I was using relative URL's instead of absolute, for pages and css file **BUT** I have a problem now, I have uploaded the file in the server, but I don't know where to place the .htaccess code

Comment: I am giving you the bounty, but I still need the answer to that last question

Comment: Thanks for acceptance. Above .htaccess will directly go under your server's `$DOCUMENT_ROOT` (probably htdocs directory).

Comment: this is the site: www.knowledge-aid.com you can check one of the news links right site of the site, and see where it will take you

Comment: Problem is in your `styles.css` URL. You have this URL: `http://localhost/DIRECTORY/AID/styles/styles.css` instead of that you should have `http://www.knowledge-aid.com/styles/styles.css`

Comment: @anabhava: I don't think the problem is with the style, because the news would have been shown without the styles. But, in this case, nothing is showing up

Comment: Still nothing. this http://knowledge-aid.com/news/3/third_news_title_for_knowledgeaid_com page is saying error page not found. How could it be a css problem?

Comment: There are 2 issues with the URL `http://knowledge-aid.com/news/3/third_news_title_for_knowledgeaid_com`. One is the css path as I mentioned in my previous comment. 2nd is that on your server your correct RewriteRule should be: `RewriteRule ^news/([0-9]+)/.*$ /news.php?id=$1 [QSA,L,NC]` (i.e. remove `/DIRECTORY/AID/` before `/news.php`)

Comment: I did everything you asked. However, not lucks! @anubhava Can you please check this: http://imm.io/PoRq screenshot for the dir/htaccess? If you can only show me how to solve the problem once. I will fix it, and will use it in the future. I just need this last problem solved only. Thanks, and sorry for the trouble.

Comment: Your .htaccess is still at wrong place. You really need to understand how your Apache web server has been setup and where is your domain's root dir. Looking at your image I think .htaccess should directly go under `knowledge-aid.com` directory.

Comment: Thank you. God bless dear. It worked. Everything is solved. Now. You are Zeus of PHP.

Comment: Glad that it is finally working for you and thanks for visiting my blog.

Answer (score 1):

> In the AID/ folder along with `index.php` & `news.php` The problem, is I don't know how to get the data from the url in the `news.php`

The htaccess file needs to be in your document root. When the request URI is in the form:

```
/news/1234/something-something
```

The order apache uses to resolve whether overrides (i.e. stuff in htaccess files) should be applied is first see if this is a directory `/news/1234/something-something` and if so, if there's an htaccess file in it. That's not a directory so apache moves on. If `/news/1234` is a directory, and if so, see if there's an htaccess file in it; since it's not, nothing happens. Then apache checks if `/news` is a directory and if so, check for htaccess; it's also not a directory so nothing happens. Finally, apache checks the document root `/` to see if there's an htaccess. Since the document root **is** a directory, that's where you need to put your rules.

The `/DIRECTORY/AID/` directory is never in the mix here, unless that is actually where your document root is. If `DIRECTORY/AID/` is your document root, e.g. the URI `/` maps directly to that directory, then you need to change your rules to:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^news/([0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)$ news.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: I changed the code, but nothing. Here is a screenshot of the directory listing. I think, that might be the problem here is the link 
http://imm.io/OFXF

Comment: I just need to know, how do I get the data from the url in the news page ?

Comment: @Eritrea The htaccess file needs to be in your document root.

Comment: Thanks for effort. problem solved. I had placed .htaccess file with the index files

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're expecting to be able to read the last portion of the URL as `$_GET['title']`, but your htaccess rule isn't adding it to the query string.

Try changing

```
RewriteRule ^news/([0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)$ DIRECTORY/AID/news.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

to

```
RewriteRule ^news/([0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)$ DIRECTORY/AID/news.php?id=$1&title=$2 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Ok, was worth a shot. I thought maybe your system was trying to find it based on the title as well as id

Comment: Thanks, +10 for the effort